# Which design pattern should follow while developing react native application?

Tags: react-native

I am newbie to react native.I would like to build an application using react native,but before that I want to know which design pattern/framework does react native support?

Comment: react native _is_ a framework. So is react. Flux is the recommended pattern for react applications. You can use any pattern that javascript or ES6 supports. What exactly are you asking? Are you looking for guidance on best practices? Or something else?

Comment: what I want to ask is how did we use Flux with react native?Design pattern which are used in swift,are we able to used it with react native?

Comment: See this for Flux: https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-concepts. For swift design patterns, you'd need to be specific about which patterns you are interested in.